# Kafka Connect - JDBC Connector - Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka

Hello I am trying to create a jdbc kafka connect using io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector  and getting following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
```

These are the parameters.

```
JDBC_URL= jdbc:oracle:thin:USERNAME/PASSWORD@URL:PORT:DBNAME
MODE=bulk
QUERY=select * tablename
TOPIC=topicname
POLL_INTERVAL_MS=86400000
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was because I was using ojdbc7.Using ojdbc6 did the trick for me! But I am still not sure why ojdbc7 did give this error. But its working now!

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: It's Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition